# charset não funciona

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tentando retornar uma ViewBag no dialog, até funciona, mas não suporta os acentos

[image]

Código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("@ViewBag.Erro");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o `Html.Raw()` para passar a string sem codificação do Razor.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Erro)";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @DiegoBerleis, fico feliz em ter te ajudo! Você poderia marcar a resposta como "Melhor Resposta" para ajudar outras pessoas que podem ter o mesmo problema?! Obrigado xD